# SQL Server : row_number partition based on the X number of days for the range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following input.

```
STD_IDN |   DATE_OF_JOINING    |
------- |----------------------|
158440  |2013-01-27 00:00:00   |
158442  |2013-01-01 00:00:00   |
158442  |2013-01-02 00:00:00   |
158442  |2013-01-03 00:00:00   |
158442  |2013-02-05 00:00:00   |
158442  |2013-02-09 00:00:00   |
158442  |2013-02-19 00:00:00   |
158442  |2013-03-02 10:21:30   |
158442  |2013-03-16 16:15:58   |
158442  |2013-03-29 00:00:00   |
158442  |2013-04-12 18:15:36   |
158442  |2013-04-28 08:46:59   |
158442  |2013-04-28 09:17:48   |
158442  |2013-05-16 16:15:58   |
170098  |2013-01-13 00:00:00   |
170098  |2013-01-14 00:00:00   |
170098  |2013-02-21 00:00:00   |
170098  |2013-02-26 00:00:00   |
170098  |2013-02-28 00:00:00   |
170098  |2013-06-16 00:00:00   |
170098  |2013-06-22 00:00:00   |
170098  |2013-07-26 00:00:00   |
170098  |2013-07-27 00:00:00   |
```

I would like to produce the following output when the above input is partitioned for X days(in this case say 10 days) starting from the first date for the group of "STD_IDN".

```
ROW_NUM| STD_IDN  |  DATE_OF_JOINING    |
-------|---------|----------------------|
  1    | 158440  |2013-01-27 00:00:00   |
  1    | 158442  |2013-01-01 00:00:00   |
  2    | 158442  |2013-01-02 00:00:00   |
  3    | 158442  |2013-01-03 00:00:00   |
  1    | 158442  |2013-02-05 00:00:00   |
  2    | 158442  |2013-02-09 00:00:00   |
  1    | 158442  |2013-02-19 00:00:00   |
  1    | 158442  |2013-03-02 10:21:30   |
  1    | 158442  |2013-03-16 16:15:58   |
  1    | 158442  |2013-03-29 00:00:00   |
  1    | 158442  |2013-04-12 18:15:36   |
  1    | 158442  |2013-04-28 08:46:59   |
  2    | 158442  |2013-04-28 09:17:48   |
  1    | 158442  |2013-05-16 16:15:58   |
  1    | 170098  |2013-01-13 00:00:00   |
  2    | 170098  |2013-01-14 00:00:00   |
  1    | 170098  |2013-02-21 00:00:00   |
  2    | 170098  |2013-02-26 00:00:00   |
  3    | 170098  |2013-02-28 00:00:00   |
  1    | 170098  |2013-06-16 00:00:00   |
  1    | 170098  |2013-06-22 00:00:00   |
  1    | 170098  |2013-07-26 00:00:00   |
  2    | 170098  |2013-07-27 00:00:00   |
```

I would prefer this being done in plain SQL.

Comment: If you have 11 days in a row, would these be in one group or two?

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that you want gaps of 10 days to define a group.  If so, you can use `lag()`, cumulative sums, and some logic:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by std_idn, grp order by date_of_joining) as row_num
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when date_of_joining > dateadd(day, 10, prev_doj)
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date_of_joining) over (partition by std_idn order by date_of_joining) as prev_doj
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

This should work on the data you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT stdin
    ,convert(VARCHAR(12), Date_of_Joining)
    ,count(*)
FROM Yourtable
WHERE Date_of_joining BETWEEN @start
        AND @end
GROUP BY stdin
    ,convert(VARCHAR(12), Date_of_Joining)
ORDER BY stdin
    ,convert(VARCHAR(12), Date_of_Joining)
```